# Card not flipping due to uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug, frontend

I have a card that displays one content on one side and different content when it's flipped. The flip is triggered with an onClick call on an `a` tag. However, I'm getting caught up on an uncaught reference error for `flip`. What steps should I take to debug this? I've double-checked the syntax for the html and JS (everything seems to be fine).

HTML

```
p.footer: #[a(href='#', onclick='flip()') About #[span]]
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // FLIP IT

  function flip () {
    $('.card').toggleClass('about');
  }

});
```

Error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: flip is not defined
 onclick @ (index):1
```

Comment: Move the function outside of `ready`. When defined inside `ready` it is accessible from only inside `ready`. To make it **global** and hence accessible from HTML, move it outside or define on `window` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flip()` is local to `$(document).ready` , you can't access with `onclick='flip()'`.

it would be better to use jquery to assign the handler in `ready()`.

```
$('p.footer a:contains(About)').click(flip);
```